# format dictionary using python

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to python, can someone tell me how can we change the given code into the formatted code given below . 
The data is stored in a dictionary and i want to store the formatted data also in a dictionary.
I am using python version 2.7.
Is it possible to do the same?
Can the alterations be made in the same dictionary or we need to create a new dictionary?

The code I have :

```
{
"roles":
      {
         "AA":[
            {
               "date":"20150101",
               "total":6.0
            },
            {
               "date":"20150201",
               "total":14.5
            },
            {
               "date":"20150301",
               "total":14.5
            }
         ],
         "AB":[
            {
               "date":"20150301",
               "total":1.6
            },
            {
               "date":"20150401",
               "total":1.6
            },
            {
               "date":"20150501",
               "total":7.24
            }
         ]
      }
}
```

The code I want :

```
    {
    "key" : "roles",
    "values" : [
    {
    "key": "AA",
    "values": [
      {
        "date": "20150101",
        "total": 6
      },
      {
        "date": "20150201",
        "total": 14.5
      },
      {
        "date": "20150301",
        "total": 14.5
      }
    ]
    },
    {
    "key": "AB",
    "values": [
      {
        "date": "20150301",
        "total": 1.6
      },
      {
        "date": "20150401",
        "total": 1.6
      },
      {
        "date": "20150501",
        "total": 7.24
      }
    ]
    }
    ]
    }
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide the
[shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are you sure? what you have now is actually the better format. Having a `'key'` key with the key as a value essentially contradicts the benefits of using a dictionary  as it makes it impossible to directly access the required data.

Comment: Yes i am working on a project using d3 and its the requirement of d3.js to have the data in the above format @DeepSpace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily the most robust but gets the job done as long as the input format stays consistent with the example you provided (using `pprint` only for formatted output. You don't have to install it for the code to work)

```
from pprint import pprint

output = {}
for key, value in input_dict.items():
    output['key'] = key
    output['values'] = [{'key': inner_key, 'values': inner_value}
                        for inner_key, inner_value in value.items()]

pprint(output)
```

Outputs

```
{'key': 'roles',
 'values': [{'key': 'AA',
             'values': [{'date': '20150101', 'total': 6.0},
                        {'date': '20150201', 'total': 14.5},
                        {'date': '20150301', 'total': 14.5}]},
            {'key': 'AB',
             'values': [{'date': '20150301', 'total': 1.6},
                        {'date': '20150401', 'total': 1.6},
                        {'date': '20150501', 'total': 7.24}]}]}
```